# no-www url for sub-directory/sub-domain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say example my domain is http://www.domain.com and i wanted to redirect into no-www url (http://domain.com), for that i used this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's working fine http://www.domain.com redirects to http://domain.com.

Now i have a sub-domain http://www.blog.domain.com (public_html/blog) to be redirected into no-www url http://blog.domain.com for that i used this code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

But then also www is not removing in the sub-domain url. What i am doing wrong here?

Update: My hosting provider is hostgator

Comment: Your 1st rule should have been enough for subdomain also. Is `www.blog.domain.com` using same DOCUMENT_ROOT as `domain.com`? Is there CMS framework installed for `www.blog.domain.com`?

Comment: 1) Yes, www.blog.domain.com using the same DOCUMENT_ROOT 2. Yes, installed wordpress CMS in public_html/blog

Comment: Oh ok WP is there so `http://blog.domain.com` should be using DOCUMENT_ROOT as `/public_html/blog` right?

Comment: exactly right `/public_html/blog`

Comment: ok I provided my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**

It seems there is a WP .htaccess inside `/public_html/blog` also. Add this rule **before WP rules in your `/public_html/blog/.htaccess:`**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Step 2:**

Then in WP `permalink settings` change your blog address to:

```
http://blog.domain.com
```

Comment: Ha it's worked, after i changed the url(`site url` and `home`) in the `wp_options` table. I was working this with .htaccess from yesterday...thank you so much.

Comment: Can you help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70626700/stop-www-for-sub-domain-with-htaccess