# Stop WWW for sub-domain with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my `subdomain.example.com` redirecting to `www.subdomain.example.com`.

Htaccess code :

```
# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### END WWW & HTTPS
```

I am looking for

> `example.com` to `www.example.com`
>
> `anything.example.com` to `anything.example.com`

How can i fix this?

Update : i am using one htaccess file for both subdomain and root domain and i cannot use separate htaccess file for for different domain for a reason.

**Note : please do not mark this question duplicate. i have already searched other part of stackoverflow and do not find a working solution.**

Answer (score 4):

You need restrict your rewrite condition to match only top level domain:

```sh
# ensure www. to top level domain only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[\w-]+\.(com|net|in|co\.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### END WWW & HTTPS
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: How to do without mentioning domain name in code. i have multiple alias different domain pointing to same folder and if i enter one domain in htaccess code, it wont work for other domain.

Comment: What are examples of your top level domains for which you want to add www ?

Comment: Like `example.com` `example.net` `domain.co.uk` , alias domain can be is different in name and TLD

Comment: Will those be covered with this pattern: `^[\w-]+\.(com|net|in|co\.uk)$` ?

Comment: Can it possible without using domain or domain extension?. Like you mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285074/htaccess-add-www-if-not-subdomain-if-subdomain-remove-www/35285128#35285128

Comment: `^[^.]+\.[^.]+$` pattern will match domain names with a single `dot`. So `example.com` and `example.net` will be matched but `example.co.uk` won't be matched.

Comment: Got it. so it only way to do is mentioning all TLD in htaccess like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[\w-]+\.(com|net|in|co\.uk)$` right?. there is no way for domain like `co.uk`, `net.in` etc without mentioning TLD - right?

Comment: yes that's right and I have updated answer accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240870/discussion-between-shanmuga-pradeep-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1):

Solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35285128/4643961

```
### START WWW & HTTPS

# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# remove www if subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### END WWW & HTTPS
```

Alternative :

```
### START WWW & HTTPS

# add www if not subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# remove www if subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### END WWW & HTTPS
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference :

```
# ensure www. to top level domain only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### END WWW & HTTPS
```